# Exceeding time limit for bipartite graph problem

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, bipartite

I am solving Bipartite graph problem on Coursera.
Actual problem statement is as follows:

[image: Problem statement]

I am using BFS to find if the given graph is bipartite or not but the grader is showing "time exceeded".

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    
    int BFS(vector<vector<int>> &adList,int s,int n,set<int> &visited)
    {
        #define inf 0
        vector<int> color(n+1,inf);
        color[s]=-1;
        visited.erase(s);
        queue<int> Q;
        Q.push(s);      
        

        while(!Q.empty())
        {
            int u=Q.front();
            Q.pop();

        for(int v:adList[u])
        {
            if(color[v]==inf)//if unvisited
            {
                visited.erase(v);
                Q.push(v);
                color[v]=color[u]*-1;
            }
            else
            {
                if((color[v]*color[u])>0)
                    return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int connectedComp(vector<vector<int>> &adList,int m,int n)
{
    set<int> visited;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;++i)
    {
        visited.insert(i);
    }

    int val;
    while(!visited.empty())
    {   
        int i=(*(visited.front()));
        val=BFS(adList,i,n,visited);
        if(!val)
            return 0;                   
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    vector<vector<int>> adList(n+1,vector<int>(0));
    
    for(int i=1;i<=m;++i)
    {
        int s,d;
        cin>>s>>d;
        adList[s].push_back(d);
        adList[d].push_back(s);
    }

    int val=connectedComp(adList,m,n);
    cout<<val;
}
```

According to me complexity for this code should be O(|E|+|V|) but it still times out.

> Failed case #17/27: time limit exceeded (Time used: 3.98/2.00, memory used: 42123264/536870912.)

I have gone through GFG but there also exists a same approach for this problem.

Comment: `int i=(*(visited.end()));` -- It is undefined behavior to dereference the `end()` iterator.  What value did you expect `i` to be set to?  Maybe your program goes into hyperspace because of issues like this, and has nothing to do with the algorithm.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have edited and changed  it to 'int i=(*(visited.front()));' but still it times out on grader.

Comment: I do not know what "grader" is.  Also, where is the test case or set of test cases?  You also have not verified that, if not for the time out error, whether the answers are correct.

Comment: creating a new color vector in every call to BFS makes this take n^2 time when m=0